# DB communication through proxy server

Tags: mysql, linux, proxy, odbc

My problem looks like this:

A clientele has one, with a proxy, foreclosed network. However, they want to synchronize information (using odbc-connector) with a database server running on there own Linux server. Unfortunately, only very few ports are open and they do not want to open any further ports.
My idea is that I run the database communication over one of the open ports.
Since I've not done something like this so far, and I'm not really got any further with google search. So I was unfortunately not been able to change the default port of the database server in Plesk on e.g. Port 8080.

I'll be very happy about suggestions:
Either via help changing the port OR also over other ideas, how this problem could be solved more easily.

Thank you in advance!

The system in question looks as follows:
MySQL 5.5.55
Php: 5.6
Plesk Onyx 17.0.17
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: They do not want to open a port, but they want this hack?

Comment: Yes, I find it extremely funny too... But unfortunately I can not change it. At the request that they please open the port at the proxy i get a horrified replie, that this ist not possible at all. And they suggested me to use a differen port